# Hide a portlet after logged into portal in liferay

Tags: permissions, liferay, hide

i am working on a liferay portal. My requirement is that i have a portlet namely a webcontent dislpay where is in homepage displaying some messages, but once the user is logged into the portal,the portlet which is a webcontent should not be visible .i have given view permission for guest alone but still i m able to see the portlet in my homepage after logged in.

Thanks and Regards,
S.Ponraj.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the portlet css only for this portlet, so that the portlet will be hidden when the user is sign-in.

Open portlet configuration (up-right) "Look-and-Feel" -> "Advenced Styling" and put under "Enter your custom CSS"

```
.signed-in #portlet_INSTANCE_id {
    display: none;
}
```

save and ready.

The `portlet_INSTANCE_id` you found upper of "Enter your custom CSS". For webcontent dislpay is something like `p_p_id_56_INSTANCE_8CkxspjsmzWq_`.

ps: to roll back use Firebug or Crhome-Dev-Console.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the rollback trick - it'd be hard to undo this operation otherwise :)